# fminunc does not take into account a user-supplied Hessian

Tags: algorithm, matlab, mathematical-optimization, hessian-matrix

First of all, sorry if I am asking for trivial thing but I am just learning multivariable calculus and optimization toolbox in matlab--optimization as well :)

I was testing my understanding of using **optimization toolbox** in **matlab** on a simple 2D function and tried to find some local minima but, for particular points, **matlab** or `fminunc` functions gives me the exact *starting* points with the following comment: "*Initial point is a local minimum.*". I have provided both a **gradient** and a *user-supplied* **Hessian**. I don't know whether it is **MATLAB** or me. Perhaps I made mistake defining **Hessian** but I think all is correct.

For random starting point, the function always give a proper (the closest) minimum. However for certain points, at exact maxima, the `fminunc` returns exactly the same point with above statement. Should I use different optimization algorithm or it is simply the **MATLAB** thing I need to accept? I thought providing the **Hessian** would sort it out. The **Hessian** is always a negative-defined matrix at all problematic points and that should mean the point is a maximum!!! I tested it via returned eigenvalues by `eig(hessian)`. It looks like `fminunc` does not take Hessian into account at all. What should I do to make `fminunc` work with hessians?

Cheers!



The points where `fminunc` is wrong:

```
x0 = [0 -1.5*pi];
x = fminunc(F,x0,options)/pi
x =
         0   -1.5000

x0 = [pi -pi/2];
x = fminunc(F,x0,options)/pi
x =
    1.0000   -0.5000

x0 = [-pi 1.5*pi];
x = fminunc(F,x0,options)/pi
x =
   -1.0000    1.5000
```

For instance the for the last point:

```
[minimum,gradient,hessian] = F([-pi 1.5*pi])
minimum =
     1
gradient =
   1.0e-15 *
   -0.1225    0.1837
hessian =
   -1.0000   -0.0000
   -0.0000   -1.0000
```

---

I used the code below:

To draw the figure:

```
[X,Y]=meshgrid(-2*pi:4*pi/100:2*pi,-2*pi:4*pi/100:2*pi);
FF = @(X,Y) cos(X).*sin(Y);
surf(X,Y,FF(X,Y));
shading interp;
```

The code with the function that I have been testing for local minima:

```
options = optimset('GradObj','on','Hessian','user-supplied','Display','iter');
F = @(x) deal(cos(x(1)).*sin(x(2)), [-sin(x(1)).*sin(x(2)) cos(x(1)).*cos(x(2))], [-cos(x(1)).*sin(x(2)) -sin(x(1)).*cos(x(2)); -sin(x(1)).*cos(x(2)) -cos(x(1)).*sin(x(2))]);
x0 = [0 pi/2];
x = fminunc(F,x0,options)
```

Comment: What version of Matlab are you using? Shouldn't the name-value pair be `'Hessian','on'`?

Comment: Hi. I recently switched to **MATLAB** 2013. I used to use `optimset` but now there's another command called `optimoptions` but I tried both with `'Hessian','on'` and it did not change the result. The function still finds local minimum at starting point. This is quite mysterious to me, to be frank.